# How to bold custom equations in ggplot2 stat_poly_eq function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, equation

I need to bold the equations in stat_poly_eq() in ggplot2. How do I do this along with `atop` function?

Also, is there anyway to specify the coordinates of the stat_poly_eq?

```
x <- c(1:50)
y <- rnorm(50,4,1)
z <- rep(c("J","F","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"), each  = 5)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = z), data = df) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.2, colour="black") + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, color = "black", geom ="point", size = 3,show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ x ) + 
  stat_poly_eq(
    formula = my.formula, 
    aes(label = paste("atop(", ..eq.label.., ",", ..rr.label.., ")")),
    label.y = 0.9,
    parse = TRUE, 
    size = 2.5
    #, col = "black"
  )+
  facet_grid(.~z, scales = "free") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can; you can underline the equation, e.g.

```
x <- c(1:50)
y <- rnorm(50,4,1)
z <- rep(c("J","F","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"), each  = 5)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = z), data = df) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.2, colour="black") + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, color = "black", geom ="point", size = 3,show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ x ) + 
  stat_poly_eq(
    formula = x ~ y, 
    aes(label = paste("atop(underline(", ..eq.label.., "),", ..rr.label.., ")")),
    label.y = 0.9,
    parse = TRUE, 
    size = 2.5
    #, col = "black"
  )+
  facet_grid(.~z, scales = "free") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image: example_1.png]

However, everything I tried (e.g. `bold()`, `bolditalic()`) didn't work when combined with `atop()`. Perhaps it's related to [this statement in the docs](https://rdrr.io/r/grDevices/plotmath.html):

> Note that bold, italic and bolditalic do not apply to symbols, and
> hence not to the Greek symbols such as mu which are displayed in the
> symbol font. They also do not apply to numeric constants.

Even if you "bold" everything with e.g.  `theme_classic(base_family = "Arial Bold")`, the equation and R2 value aren't changed.

--

In terms of positioning the labels, you can move them around with `label.x` and `label.y`, e.g. (`label.y = 1` puts the label at the top of the plot):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)
x <- c(1:50)
y <- rnorm(50,4,1)
z <- rep(c("J","F","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"), each  = 5)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = z), data = df) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.2, colour="black") + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, color = "black", geom ="point", size = 3,show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ x ) + 
  stat_poly_eq(
    formula = x ~ y, 
    aes(label = paste("atop(underline(", ..eq.label.., "),", ..rr.label.., ")")),
    label.y = 1,
    label.x = 0.2,
    parse = TRUE, 
    size = 2.5
    #, col = "black"
  )+
  facet_grid(.~z, scales = "free") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image: example_2.png]